# When using Session variables to control my embedded YouTube player, I receive the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of null?

Tags: javascript, debugging, meteor

[A link to the page where it is deployed](http://mixtape.meteor.com)

After attempting to control using Session, the YouTube embedded player stops being responsive, and returns the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of null`. This doesn't happen everytime, but can be reproduced by entering a song in the link and clicking on the play button.

Here is the setting up of the YouTube API temporarily placed in the HTML file:

`mixtape.html`

```
<script>
// Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyD1VcsNnysOY6_Za-8kE-BK6Zh8jQwvo4w');
}
</script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad"></script>
  <script src= "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
  <script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    console.log("playerAPIready");
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '400',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });

 //console.log("loaded");
  $("#player").hide();
  }

function onPlayerReady(){
//console.log("ready");
}

function onPlayerStateChange(){
//console.log("changed");

}

function generatePlaylist(list){
    console.log("list: ", list)
    player.loadPlaylist(list);
}
  </script>
```

And the printing out occurs here. The nav_playlist reads from a Session variable which contains what it should, but the printing out below pretens that nav_playlist is empty.

```
<template name="player">
    <div id="player">
        <div id="ytplayer"></div>
        <div id="nav">
            <br>
            {{#each nav_playlist}}
                  {{> unremovable_track}}   
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```

An in `mixtape.js`

```

```
  Template.player.nav_playlist = function(){
    return Session.get("current_list");
  }
```

```

And here are the Session variables being given their values. These contain exactly what they should. They update when the user clicks the play button.

```
/*Update List on generate button*/
Template.list.updateList = function(){
    var ret = [];
        $( "#playlist .list_element" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
        ret.push(   Links.findOne({_id:$(this).attr('id')})   );
         }
    });

    var urls = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ret.length; i++){
        urls[i] = ret[i].videoId;
    }

    Session.set("current_list",ret);
    Session.set("current_urls",urls);
}
```

And finally this is where the toggling happens to unhide the YouTube player and start the video.

```
  Template.header.events({
    'click #generate_button': function (evt, template){
        //bad code below:

    Template.list.updateList();

    if (Template.list.my_playlist().fetch().length == 0){

        alert('Your tape is empty!');
    }
    else{
        generatePlaylist(  Session.get("current_urls")  );
        $("#playlist").css('display','none');
        $("#player").fadeIn(1000);

        $(".absolute_center").hide();

        /*Things to hide*/
        $(".absolute_center2").fadeIn();

        $("#query").hide();
        $("#share").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#playlist_container").fadeOut(1000);

        $('body').animate({backgroundColor: 'rgb(53,53,53)'}, 'slow');
        $('#title').animate({color: '#fff'}, 'slow');
    }
    },

    'click #close_player': function (evt, template){        
        player.stopVideo();
        $(".absolute_center2").hide();
        $("#player").hide();
        $("#playlist").css('display','block');

        /*Things that must reappear*/
        $("#query").show();
        $("#share").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".absolute_center").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#playlist_container").fadeIn(1000);

        $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#fff'}, 'slow');
        $('#title').animate({color: '#000'}, 'slow');

    }

  });
```

[Here is the GitHub page if you would like to look at the source and dig deeper](https://github.com/alouis93/music-meteor)

Comment: your first link appears to be dead

Comment: @jyarbro Are you certain? I was just able to click it. Try pasting it into your browser: http://mixtape.meteor.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that although you're waiting for the YouTube API to load before adding the iFrame, you're not waiting for the DOM to finish rendering, so the element you're trying to replace with the iFrame (`ytplayer`) doesn't actually exist when `new YT.Player` is called in the script tag.  Any time you try to play, stop, change video or anything else on the player you've initialised will result in this error under these circumstances, even if the relevant element is subsequently added to the DOM.  You can manually run the code in the script tag in the console, and you should find that everything then works as the element will by that point exist at player reinitialisation.

I would advise moving this whole code segment into a `Template.player.rendered` function in the js file.  You'll need to check whether the player has already been created (and only run the code if it hasn't), but putting it all here rather than a script tag will guarantee that the element exists as well as that the API has been loaded.  Anyway, I'm sure you can work it out.

**UPDATE:**
Since you're doing most of the work in the script tags through callbacks, it's actually much easier to add this to the js file:

```
Template.player.created = function() {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
};
```

and take this line out of the html:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad"></script>
```

Apologies if what I said above isn't clear.  In your version, the YouTube API is trying to replace the div `ytplayer` with an iFrame, but since the Javascript is in a script tag, it's being run before Meteor has finished rendering all your templates, which means that `ytplayer` doesn't yet exist in the DOM and so it doesn't get replaced.  So although `player` exists, you can't do anything with it, since there's no iFrame in the DOM.  By making the change above, you will only load the YouTube API once the template containing `ytplayer` has been loaded for the first time, guaranteeing a successful replacement.

Note that if you have any significant latency, the YouTube API might not get round to firing the callbacks until the DOM has fully rendered, in which case the whole thing would work, which I assume it did sporadically.

Comment: Trying to understand your comment - so the API loads, does not wait for the `new YT.Player` to render on the DOM, so whenever I call a stop, play action, I get the error?

And where to you suggest the `Template.player.rendered` function is called from? The `onPlayerReady` function?

Comment: I still receive the same error message after including your fix. Were you able to make it function normally after pasting the <script> tag into your console?

Comment: I actually got the video using your fix, much thanks! However, the navigation list dependent on the Session variable then stopped working. I moved it into a separate template, and now everything works as it should.